# Formatting conflicts: Proc format and Call define - proc report

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I have a sample code like this:

```
**Variable Condition**  
   1        Stable
   2        Unstable
   3        Unstable
   4        Stable
   5        Stable
   6        Stable
 Average    Unstable
```

I'm working on the ods tagsets.excelxp to export this data using the proc Reporting. 
I created a PROC FORMAT to declare a formatting for the Condition column: (If condition=Unstable, the background's color is red and otherwise its green). I applied this format on my PROC REPORT using:

> define Condition/style(column)=   [];

Next, i want to apply a format to my last row (Average) using the compute statement:

```
COMPUTE Variable;  
IF Variable= 'Average' THEN CALL DEFINE(_COL_,'style', 'style [fontweight=bold 
background='gray']'); 
ENDCOMP;
```

The problem is that i want to keep my red background in my last cell in the Average Row (the value='Unstable'), which is turned into gray because of the Comput Statement. In other words, i want my last cell to be bold (keep the fontweight option in the compute statement) and to be red (keep the color in the define statement).

Thank you.

Comment: This would be a better question if you included a complete set of code (which you come close to, but not close enough) to replicate the issue.